# Hibernates - Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class exception

Tags: java, hibernate, intellij-idea

I've seen that this exception is quite common when working with Hibernate, but I see also that there are many different causes for it.

After going through several threads and forums I am not able to fin the solution to my problem, so any advice or suggestion would be very appretiated.

I am trying to implement a hierarchy in my database as follows:
[image: Structure of the database]

I have 7 tables which relations are:

- One Category can have many subcategories registered
- One Subcategory can have many AProductXXX registered
- And the bottom tables (iPhone, Samsung, Bosh, Philips, Hammer) extends form their corresponding abstract class.

The error I am having is the following:

```
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.AnnotationException: Use of @OneToMany or @ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class: com.xxx.tutorial.SubcategoryMobilePhone.children[com.xxx.tutorial.AProductPhone]
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindManyToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:1236)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder.bindStarToManySecondPass(CollectionBinder.java:800)
at org.hibernate.cfg.annotations.CollectionBinder$1.secondPass(CollectionBinder.java:725)
at org.hibernate.cfg.CollectionSecondPass.doSecondPass(CollectionSecondPass.java:54)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1621)
at org.hibernate.boot.internal.InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.processSecondPasses(InFlightMetadataCollectorImpl.java:1589)
at org.hibernate.boot.model.process.spi.MetadataBuildingProcess.complete(MetadataBuildingProcess.java:278)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.metadata(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:858)
at org.hibernate.jpa.boot.internal.EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.build(EntityManagerFactoryBuilderImpl.java:885)
at org.hibernate.jpa.HibernatePersistenceProvider.createEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistenceProvider.java:58)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:55)
at javax.persistence.Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory(Persistence.java:39)
at com.xxx.tutorial.App.main(App.java:13)
```

Here is the code of the SubcategoryMobilePhone and its relations, but I have the same problem with the other branches:

```
import javax.persistence.*;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

@Entity
@Table(name = "mobile_phone")
public class SubcategoryMobilePhone extends ASubcategory {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
@JoinColumn(name = "mobilePhone_id")
Set<AProductPhone> children = new HashSet<>();

public void addChild(AProductPhone child){
    this.children.add(child);
}

public Integer getId() {
    return id;
}

public void setId(Integer id) {
    this.id = id;
}

public Set<AProductPhone> getChildren() {
    return children;
}

public void setChildren(Set<AProductPhone> children) {
    this.children = children;
}
}
```

**AProductPhone**

```
import javax.persistence.Column;

import javax.persistence.MappedSuperclass;

@MappedSuperclass
public abstract class AProductPhone {

@Column(name = "name", length = 64)
String name;

public AProductPhone(String name){
    this.name = name;
}

public AProductPhone(){}

public String getName() {
    return name;
}

public void setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
}
}
```

**iPhone class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "iphone")
public class iPhone extends AProductPhone {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "releaseYear")
    private Integer releaseYear;

    @Column(name = "iPhone_version")
    private String iphoneVersion;

    @Column(name = "iPhone_surname")
    private String iphoneSurname;

    public iPhone(String name, String iphoneSurname, Integer releaseYear, String iphoneVersion){
        super(name);
        this.iphoneSurname = iphoneSurname;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.iphoneVersion = iphoneVersion;
    }

    public iPhone(){super();}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(Integer releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    public String getIphoneVersion() {
        return iphoneVersion;
    }

    public void setIphoneVersion(String iphoneVersion) {
        this.iphoneVersion = iphoneVersion;
    }

    public String getIphoneSurname() {
        return iphoneSurname;
    }

    public void setIphoneSurname(String iphoneSurname) {
        this.iphoneSurname = iphoneSurname;
    }
}
```

**Samsung class**

```
import javax.persistence.*;

@Entity
@Table(name = "samsung")
public class Samsung extends AProductPhone{

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name = "id")
    private Integer id;

    @Column(name = "releaseYear")
    private Integer releaseYear;

    @Column(name = "samsung_version")
    private String samsungVersion;

    @Column(name = "samsung_surname")
    private String samsungSurname;

    public Samsung(String name, String samsungSurname, Integer releaseYear, String samsungVersion){
        super(name);
        this.samsungSurname = samsungSurname;
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
        this.samsungVersion = samsungVersion;
    }

    public Samsung(){super();}

    public Integer getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(Integer id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public Integer getReleaseYear() {
        return releaseYear;
    }

    public void setReleaseYear(Integer releaseYear) {
        this.releaseYear = releaseYear;
    }

    public String getSamsungVersion() {
        return samsungVersion;
    }

    public void setSamsungVersion(String samsungVersion) {
        this.samsungVersion = samsungVersion;
    }

    public String getSamsungSurname() {
        return samsungSurname;
    }

    public void setSamsungSurname(String samsungSurname) {
        this.samsungSurname = samsungSurname;
    }
}
```

Despite of the **iPhone** and **Samsung** classes are similar, don't think about them, as I am working in an example only, I just want two tables, one for iPhone entities, and other for Samsung entities.

The problem is that in the SubcategoryMobilePhone class, I have the following line, which is the one I think throws the exception:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "mobilePhone_id")
    Set<AProductPhone> children = new HashSet<>();
```

As **AProductPhone** is not an entity, but an abstract class, I think the problem is there. I cannot set this abstract class as an @Entity and a @MappedSuperclass at the same time, but I neither want to have a table called *AProductPhone*. I need this class so I can retrieve from the database the set of "Mobile Phone types" that are registered on the SubcategoryMobilePhone class, but as they can be from different concrete classes, I want to have an abstract one extending them so I can retrieve them properly.

I've seen also that it is needed to specify in the persistence.xml file the entity classes, so here is my persistence.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence"
             xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
             xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence
             http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
    <persistence-unit name="com.xxx.tutorial.mysqlHibernates">
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.Category</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.SubcategoryMobilePhone</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.SubcategoryWashingMachine</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.SubcategoryTools</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.iPhone</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.Samsung</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.Bosh</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.Philips</class>
        <class>com.xxx.tutorial.Hammer</class>

        <properties>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.driver_class" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/nested_parent_child_hibernate_multiple_tables_example"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.autocommit" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.username" value="root"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.password" value=""/>
            <property name="hibernate.dialect" value="org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.CharSet" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding" value="utf8"/>
            <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode" value="true"/>
            <property name="hibernate.show_sql" value="false"/>
            <property name="hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto" value="update"/>
            <!-- use encache provider-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.region.factory_class"-->
            <!--value="org.hibernate.cache.ehcache.EhCacheRegionFactory"/>-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.javax.cache.provider" value="org.ehcache.jsr107.EhcacheCachingProvider"/>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;use second level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_second_level_cache" value="true"/>-->
            <!--&lt;!&ndash;use 3rd level cache&ndash;&gt;-->
            <!--<property name="hibernate.cache.use_query_cache" value="true"/>-->
        </properties>
    </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

What I have to do to be able to manage a hierarchy like that? what I am doing wrong here or what am I missing? I think I have identified the issue, but don't know how to solve it

---

**EDIT:**
To summarize and clarify what I'm trying to do, I have the following classes hierarchy in my Java project (using Maven):

```
class Category
-- abstract class ASubcategory
class SubcategoryMobilePhone extends ASubcategory
class SubcategoryWashingMachine extends ASubcategory
class SubcategoryTools extends ASubcategory
-- abstract class AProductPhone
class iPhone extends AProductPhone
class Samsung extends AProductPhone
-- abstract class AProductWashingMachine
class Bosh extends AProductWashingMachine
class Philips extends AProductWashingMachine
-- abstract class AProductTools
class Hammer extends AProductTools
```

And this is the structure I want to create in my MySQL database using Hibernate:

```
Category
-SubcategoryMobilePhone
---iPhone
---Samsung
-SubcategoryWashingMachine
---Bosh
---Philips
-SubcategoryTools
---Hammer
```

I don't want the abstract classes to be added as tables in the database.

All the tables have a list of children, and a reference to their parents through the FK. So, for example, the `SubcategoryMobilePhone` class have a `Set<AProductPhone> children` to store children that can be either *iPhones* or *Samsungs*, and a reference to its parent, which is `Category`. Same with the rest of entities. How can I do that without become crazy with the Hibernate annotations?

Answer (score 0):

The mapping you have for `AProductPhone` doesn't use hibernate inheritance and that causes the problem. You need use the `@Inheritance` annotation using the table-per-subclass strategy (assuming you want a different table per subclass). This will create one table for the superclass and one table per subclass.

As an example (imagine an abstract bank account with 2 subtypes):

```
@Entity
@Inheritance(
      strategy= InheritanceType.TABLE_PER_CLASS
)
@DiscriminatorColumn(name="TYPE")
public abstract class Account {
   @Id
   private Long id;

   private double balance;

   [...]
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("CHECKING")
public class CheckingAccount extends Account {
   private double checkLimitAmount;
   [...]
}

@Entity
@DiscriminatorValue("SAVINGS")
public class SavingsAccount extends Account  {
   private double atmLimit;
   [...]
}
```

With the configuration above, one can have a `@OneToMany List<Account>` mapped from other entities.

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But, what if Idon't want to have the Account table in the database? As an abstract class, I only want this class to support me when I want to create a list of entities from other classes that extend it but, it is mandatory to have also the Account table stored in my database? I won't use it in any case, as I will have the concrete classes with their corresponding table in the database (in my case, the table I don't want to have in the database is AProductPhone)

Comment: @daniellozano `@MappedSuperclass` if you want to have child entities also map the fields of a parent entity

Comment: @XtremeBaumer thanks! But I tried to use MappedSuperclass for AProductPhone (check my question where I place the code for AProductPhone), but I get this error: Use of OneToMany or ManyToMany targeting an unmapped class. Augusto suggest to use Inheritance, but that creates an AProductPhone table on the database and that is something I don't want. This exception is because the MappedSuperclass annotation, or it can appear maybe because of I'm not doing properly the mapping between the child entities and their parent?

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38544422/7109162) to a similar problem.  They use an interface as type argument for the list. However, with your current mapping, you are running into an issue with duplicate identifiers. It would be much more feasible, to have just 1 `AProductPhone` table and then have a field `type` to which you set the type name (samsung, iphone). Especially since they have the same fields anyways

Comment: @daniellozano I get your point. There are a couple of mapping strategies in the [hibernate docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/4.3/manual/en-US/html/ch10.html#inheritance-tableperconcrete) that explain how to have a table per concrete class. I haven't used them before and there are some notes about their drawbacks. One of the drawbacks is that you cannot have a polymophic one-to-many associations. If you feel strong about not using one of the classical mapping stragies (single table or table per subclass) maybe JPA is not the right technology for your problem.